# Loc function is not working in pandas (My df.loc Command is not working)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The df.loc is either working on the first row or not working

The data i have in the column Narration is :

```
x 23

cricket 22

rev 11

polo 22
```

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

narr=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\sports.csv')
narr.head(4)
df=pd.DataFrame(narr)
df.loc[(df.Narration == 'cricket') | (df.Narration  == 'rev'), 'name_match'] = 'Match'  
df.loc[(df.Narration == 'polo') | (df.Narration  == 'x'), 'name_match'] = 'NotMatch'
print(df)
```

The result i am geeing is

```
   Narration   name_match
0        x 23        NaN
1  cricket 22        NaN
2      rev 11        NaN
3     polo 22        NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide print-outs from `df` after reading it in from `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Well it makes sense to me. The value you have in 'Narration' is `crocket 22` not `cricket`. Same for `rev`, `polo` and `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
df.loc[df.Narration.str.contains('rev') | 
       df.Narration.str.contains('cricket'), 'name_match'] = 'Match'

df.loc[df.Narration.str.contains('polo') | 
       df.Narration.str.contains('x'), 'name_match'] = 'NotMatch'

df
```

Output:

```
    Narration name_match
0        x 23   NotMatch
1  cricket 22      Match
2      rev 11      Match
3     polo 22   NotMatch
```

Comment: What if the Narration column has two same names.

Comment: For eg rev polo 22. i want it in Match

Comment: Cricket x i want it in not match

Comment: Just remove the Or and second condition.